# Determining irregular area of a CCSprite

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

In my simple game I use `boundingBox` for picking coins and other stuff, but I need use irregular area detection of Sprite (without Alpha). Is there an alternative to `boundingBox`?

Here is code:

```
-(void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
CGPoint point = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
curentPosition = point;
arrToDel = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
// Находим спрайт под касанием

if (CGRectContainsPoint([some boundingBox], curentPosition)) {
    CCLOG(@"popal"); 
}

CCSprite *coin = nil;

for (Coins *coins in self.bugs) {
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([coins boundingBox], curentPosition)) {
        coin = coins; // нашли монету
    }
}

if (coin != nil) {
    NSMutableArray *checkList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];

    for (Coins *coins in self.bugs) {
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect([coin boundingBoxInPixels], [coins boundingBox]) && coins != coin) {
            [checkList addObject:coins];
        }
    }

    int max = coin.zOrder;

    for (Coins *b in checkList) {
        if (b.zOrder > max)
            max = b.zOrder;
    }

    if (max == coin.zOrder) {

        [self removeChild:coin cleanup:YES];
        podsciot++;
        CCLOG(@"%i",podsciot);

        [arrToDel addObject:coin];

        for (Coins *coins in  arrToDel) {
            if (coins.type == kKey) {
                coinsCount++;
                CCLOG(@"SeriiZ --> %i", coinsCount);
            }

            [self.bugs removeObject:coin];

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally recommend Box2D and PhysicsEditor if you need irregular shapes. It has a slight learning curve (Box2D), but is well worth it for most uses.

[Box2D (although it comes with Cocos2D and has a template built in)](http://code.google.com/p/box2d/)

[PhysicsEditor (not free, but I recommend it as the program is very easy to use and the developer is a kind man)](http://www.physicseditor.de/)

It isn't only for Physics simulation. You can use it only for collision detection if you like. Ray Wenderlich's site has a nice tutorial for just that:

[Box2D For Just Collision Detection](http://www.raywenderlich.com/606/how-to-use-box2d-for-just-collision-detection-with-cocos2d-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with `CGPath`.

This tutorial helped me http://bobueland.com/cocos2d/?p=134